# Gingerbread,HoneyComb,ICS ROM for Galaxy S

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I  have recently purchased a galaxy S with Froyo to do some tests on my App. I would like to upgrade to use ROM like Gingerbread, Honeycomb,ICS. I have searched the web and I have found many ROMs but i can't tell if they are trusted or not (no bugs, no low performance..). I would appreciate if someone points me to some ROMs that he had used before for these Android version. I know that I can use Nandroid Backup if I disliked one tested ROM. Does some Roms able to turn my phone out of service?

Comment: ROM recommendations are off-topic, sorry, the question I've linked is the closest we get.  Check out our [FAQ].

Comment: However this is a specific ROM recommendation?

Comment: @SmartLemon those are even worse as they're subjective and become obsolete fast.

Comment: But isn't a question meant to be specific? And not so broad that the user will be overwhelmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not install HoneyComb on the galaxy s. HoneyComb is designed for tablets, not phones.

Secondy most of the roms on XDA are good, just check the comments and see whats wrong with them.

Check out this post here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1398223 seems pretty legit, only a couple of bugs that hardly matter (check below)

Bugs:

```
Lockscreen occasionally does not react to touch
Formatting external sd formats internal
Facebook sync pictures are low res(but at least it works)probably not fixable from our end
```